# Headless browser unable to navigate between pages

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, headless, google-chrome-headless

I am trying to drive a headless browser to login to cloud-based payroll software that my company uses. But it couldn't even get past the logging-in stage. The code works fine when in 'head' mode. Below are my codes:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless") # Runs Chrome in headless mode.
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox') # Bypass OS security model
# options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')  # applicable to windows os only
options.add_argument('start-maximized') #
options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path='/Applications/chromedriver')
print("Headless Chrome Initialized on MacOS")

# Navigate to website
browser.get('https://sg.quickhr.co')
print('Navigate to quickHR website')

# Login to quickHR
print('Keying in credentials')
# Define credentials and key-in accordingly
email = 'user@user.com'
password = '********'
browser.find_element_by_id('inputName').send_keys(email)
browser.find_element_by_id('inputPassword').send_keys(password)
browser.find_element_by_id('validate_login_lb').click()
print('Logging in')

# Wait for login to complete and webpage and elements to load before proceeding
try:
    WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'flaticon-payroll')))
finally:
    browser.find_element_by_class_name('flaticon-payroll')
```

And below is my error code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/cadellteng/PycharmProjects/Playground/login.py", line 71, in <module>
    browser.find_element_by_class_name('flaticon-payroll').click()
  File "/Users/cadellteng/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 80, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "/Users/cadellteng/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/Users/cadellteng/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Users/cadellteng/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: headless chrome=79.0.3945.130)
```

So apparently is not interactable. I'm not sure what it means as this routine works when it is not headless.

Comment: Do you have a demo username/password credentials for us to use?

Comment: There is no demo as I don't own the software. Sorry about that

Comment: Can you update the question with the relevant HTML?

Comment: `<a href="https://sg.quickhr.co/payroll-module/views/" class="nav-link"><i class="fa flaticon-payroll"></i><p>Payroll</p></a>`